# Anonymous Login in Openfire with Strophe

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am running openfire 3.6.4 and connecting with Strophe library. The setup is working fine. Now i want to do one thing i want a anonymous login for my application and that login should also get subscribed to a room and receive the notification of that room. I have enabled the anonymous setting in openfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by changing strophe.js 
 

find: 
`if (Strophe.getNodeFromJid(this.jid) === null &&
            do_sasl_anonymous) {`

 Change to : 

 `if (Strophe.getNodeFromJid(this.jid) === '' &&
            do_sasl_anonymous) {`

By changing the comparison of the Jid node from null to empty, I was able to authenticate anonymously when only submitting the domain part of the Jid, and still was able to authenticate with DIGEST when sumitting the full Jid and the password.

Comment: In the latest version I didn't need to modify strophe. Useing the domain as the JID and null password did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

First, enable SASL ANONYMOUS in Strophe by passing in null for username and password to `connect()`:

```
connection.connect(null,
                   null,
                   onConnect);
```

Next, just send presence to room@conference_service/nick:

```
var pres = $pres({to: 'room@conference_service/nick'});
connection.send(pres);
```

Comment: i did that i passed blank username and password on connect but it get terminate

Comment: and passing null it gives me <not-authorized/></failure>

Comment: Try sending just the server name in connect as the username, without your strophe.js mod?