# login anonymous openfire

Tags: openfire, strophe

I followed this :

[Anonymous Login in Openfire with Strophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114259/anonymous-login-in-openfire-with-strophe)

i put the domain as the username and password null. The openfire propertie  xmpp.auth.anonymous = true

i tried many configurations e Nothing works. What am i missing ?

I´m using backbone and underscore. here is my code

```
   _.extend(Chat.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    connect : function() {
        var self = this;    
        this.connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
        this.connection.connect('brent029', null, function(status) {
            self.onConnect(status);   
        });
    },

    onConnect : function(status) {
        switch(status) {
            case Strophe.Status.CONNECTED:
                this.sendPresConference();
                break;
            default:
                break;
       }
    },


    sendPresConference : function(){
        this.connection.send(
            $pres({
                to : 'room@conference_service/nick'
            })
            .c('x',{ 
                xmlns : Strophe.NS.MUC 
            }).tree()
        );
    },
```

Comment: I didn't understand why someone voted against this issue.

I searched several links about it. All they say to put the domain as user and password as null. I did that and not worked.

Then, in openfire have the option xmpp.auth.anonymous. I put true.

And yet nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

openfire have a property sasl.mechs

the value of this property it was  "PLAIN".

i changed the value to "ANONYMOUS,PLAIN".

Then, i restarted the openfire and now works fine.